# Building a framework with Carthage in Xcode

Tags: xcode, frameworks, carthage

My framework is dependent on multiple frameworks which I have tried to imbed in my framework via prior Linking Binary with Libraries and adding a Copy Files with Destination set to Frameworks under build phases with all the dependencies. These schemes are also set to "Shared" setting.

On carthage build --no-skip-current

My framework builds nicely but the dependencies, now found within the Frameworks folder contains all of the dependencies without their respective header folder/files so that on their use they could not be found.

Please let me know if I am missing any steps as it is very important that I can access these header files.

Note: I am extremely new at building frameworks and using carthage.

Thank you.

Comment: So the workaround I found is to remove all the frameworks my framework was dependent on and replace them with the frameworks Carthage built, as these ones have the Header files. From there these new frameworks will be available from my custom framework but they still need to be linked to the project that's using my custom framework through Build Phases' "Link Binary with Libraries" for my project to be able to access these dependencies.

Comment: Feel your pain. I wrote down a set of workflows to refer back to when i forget how to manage nested frameworks and carthage: check it out: http://stylekit.org/blog/2017/02/03/Carthage-and-nested-frameworks/

Comment: @GitSyncApp I was having some trouble figuring this out, and I find your tutorial really handy, thanks. I have one question about the pre-requisite,4. 'setting the build path' though, it should be set to custom, absolute, and then `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build` ?

Comment: @Mayerz Thanks for pointing that out. It should be: "Framework search path" and not "Build path" You find this setting under build settings in your xcode project. (I've corrected the blog post)

Comment: @GitSyncApp Thanks! Also, after following your tutorial should we be able to debut framework directly from the application using it? It appears that I can't. I guess it's normal right?

Comment: debug? There are two framework search paths. one for debug and one for release. You set both. That should give you error and print messages. Personally I walked away from Carthage. I now use SPM. Which I wrote 4 blog posts about. SPM is way easier to use and a lot faster than developing with Carthage both in terms of build speed and workflow wise. Only drawback is that iOS is not fully supported yet. I develop for mac.

Comment: @Mayerz Carthage is good SPM is magical✨, check out what is possible: http://stylekit.org/blog/2017/02/25/The-ultimate-XCode-workflow/

Comment: Ok i will check it out, thanks! We were worrier about choosing something that has not been used much yet @GitSyncApp

Comment: @GitSyncApp wow that looks exciting. I found some typos in your articles. On monday I will try that and leave comments. Thanks for your experimentations

Comment: @Mayerz Thanks. Feel free to ask. I'm eager to find edge cases my self.

Comment: @GitSyncApp join the swift-lang slack do we can discuss further!

Comment: @Mayerz I'm there. under the handle: eonist